# jQuery UI Accordion 1.6

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

I'm using the jQuery UI Accordion 1.6 (http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion),  I've changed it a bit and made it work as I need and want it to work. There is just a few things off about it, but one of the major ones is something I just simply can't figure out how to make it work.

The plugin is working as intended, it actually closes, opens, opens again, closes all together, etc. However, I'm trying to get the "Posted by..." information right underneath the Headline text. Also, I want the AUTHOR and 0 comments part to be a separate link, the problem is that they are inside the A CLASS (which opens the accordion). Maybe this isn't even a issue with the plugin, but I've run up on options.

The jQuery is calling "A" here:
I've tried switching this A to a div, but it just breaks. I thought, "Oh I have to alter my CSS", but either I'm doing it wrong, or its not even a jQuery issue, but a CSS one...I just can't figure this out rahhh@#$! Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the example I'm working with; http://www.notedls.com/demo

```
$.extend($.ui.accordion, {
defaults: {
    selectedClass: "selected",
    alwaysOpen: true,
    animated: 'slide',
    event: "click",
    header: "a",
    autoheight: true,
    running: 0,
    navigationFilter: function() {
        return this.href.toLowerCase() == location.href.toLowerCase();
    }
},
```

Comment: I can't make any sense of this question.  You're using Accordion and it's not working.  I got that.  The rest of it... ???  You wrote: *The jQuery is calling "A" here.*  What does that mean?
I clicked but didn't see an obvious accordion on the demo.  It looked like a tab interface, not an accordion.  Also, I didn't see any glaring problem with it, and I can't figure out what your description of the problem means.  My suggestion: start over, simplify, boil it down. Start with the simplest thing.  Then successively add one small thing at a time until you get stuck. Then ask.

Comment: ps: the actual jQueryUI Accordion at the location you referenced (http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion) is v1.8, not v1.6?   Are you really using v1.6?    There's a demonstration of the v1.8 jQueryUI accordion at http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/ , if you want a good starting point.

Comment: A trigger = 

    header: "a",

Comment: ?? A trigger = header "a" ??  That doesn't clarify anything.

Answer (score 0):

To get the posted by under the title, try around line 220 in noted.css, change the line-height:

```
ul.ui-accordion-container li a.acc1 {
line-height:1em;
}
```

The author and the comment count really are the same line of code, so you'll need to add in a < br/ > or, ideally, some proper sementic markup if you want to separate them.

Comment: You were able to decipher the question? But *how..?*